# Count JSON objects where value is x

Tags: jquery, json

I want to use jQuery to count all alarms where almSeverity = "1". I get the following JSON response from a web service:

```
{
"notification": "Alarm search is complete",
"alarmList": [
  {
     "almId": 1,",
     "almSeverity": "1"
  },
  {
     "almId": 2,
     "almSeverity": "2"
  },
  {
     "almId": 3,
     "almSeverity": "1"
  }
]
}
```

I count all alarms like so:

```
data.alarmList.length;
```

...but what would be the best way to count the alarms where almSeverity is 1?

Comment: create a custom json parser function and counting the no. of almSeverity are equal to 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have a javascript array, not JSON, and if so you can just filter it

```
data.alarmList.filter(function(x) {
    return x.almSeverity == '1';
}).length
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/btuuLhdt/1/)